# ubuntu server, trying to get a service/daemon to start

Tags: ubuntu, daemon

I followed the instructions [here](http://peterlairdtech.blogspot.com/2010/05/example-linux-startup-service-for.html#comment-form), but when I enter "sudo service mydaemon start".  I get "mydaemon: unrecognized service".  I have verified that the files are in the proper places, and I took the additional step of making my script file (echoHW.sh) executable, still no success.  Any help whatsoever would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typed `sudo crontab -e` and then selected `nano` as my editor. It brought up nano with the below comments. I added my script at the bottom and then rebooted. My tasks are now running whenever the system is booted.

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

Comment: MAN I wish that had worked, but it didn't.  Is there someplace I can look at a log file that might tell me what went wrong.

Comment: Actually, I checked the cron log, and it DID run.  So now I've got to take a look at my scripts.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you located and tried running the service the service in /etc/init.d/(service name)?

I am unfamiliar with invoking services without actually running the shell program located under init.d folder but I am sure if the shell program to start the service is located under init.d then it should be an easy setup so you can invoke it the way you wish - "service mydaemon [command]"

Comment: If you mean "sudo service /etc/init.d/mydaemon start", I just tried that (when sitting in /etc/init.d/), and got "/etc/init.d/mydaemon: unrecognized service".

Comment: In that case I would be concerned about the service properly installing on the machine, or that the shell command to start the program simply doesn't exist in the init.d folder for whatever reason.  I am not a Linux pro by any means so I am unsure of how to assist from here.  Is it a package you downloaded?  Or is it a daemon/service you wrote?

Comment: It was just the files as described in the page I referenced.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get that error if the script is not executable

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/mydaemon
```

Comment: The OP did state that the script was executable.

Comment: He made "echoHW.sh" executable, which from the article is the program to be called by the init script.
I am saying that the script in init.d should be executable as well, Otherwise it raises the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up Port Forwarding on your router? If not, setup port forwarding and your static ip adress + DNS (which you will need from a DNS provider or have your own DNS server). Port Forwarding [Here.](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Port_Forwarding)

Comment: It's all local at this point, ports aren't the issue.